# How do I detect if the program already defined the system variable?

Tags: vbscript, undefined-variable

I need to use a system variable ***VarX*** within system function ***DetailLine_Refresh()***.

When the program executes, function ***DetailLine_Refresh()*** will be executed a few times (this is the program design and I can not change anything).

However, system only defined ***VarX*** at the second/ third times when the function executed.

Therefore, programs throws an error "**Variable not defined**" whenever it executes function *DetailLine_Refresh()* on the first time.

My question is, how do I avoid program to run my ***if statement*** below before the program defined the system variable ***VarX***?

Thank you in advance.

```
Function DetailLine_Refresh()
    If VarX = "A" or VarX = "B" Then
        FunctionAB()
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Use `IsEmpty()` - See [VBScript Documentation - IsEmpty Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/5cs4befa(v=vs.84))

Comment: @user692942 I don't think testing for Empty is going to help. Isn't the cause of this error because the variable hasn't been dimmed yet? The proper solution would then be to A) avoid global variables, or B) make sure the global variables are all defined in the beginning of the execution.

Comment: @GeertBellekens Honestly from what they have provided it's hard to know what they are or aren't doing. It just sounded like they are trying to call a function before a variable has been initialised so `IsEmpty()` would help with that.